# Stuck with List Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

```
word = "There are seven wonders of the world"
x = word.split()
new = [len(i) for i in x if len(i)>3]
print(new)

>>> [5, 5, 7, 5]
```

This snippet prints a list of **lengths** of the words in the variable **word** whose len is greater than 3, BUT I also want to print the words along with the list of lengths, HOW?

Comment: Perhaps `new = [(i, len(i)) for i in x if len(i)>3]`?

Comment: @Nick Thanks man, got it, it was so simple smh

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a tuple `(i, len(i))` instead of just `len(i)`:

```
word = "There are seven wonders of the world"
x = word.split()
new = [(i, len(i)) for i in x if len(i)>3]
print(new)
```

which would give you the output:

```
[('There', 5), ('seven', 5), ('wonders', 7), ('world', 5)]
```